# How to use libxml2 validate a xml with a schema in version 1.1?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, libxml2

I use libxml2 to validate xmls with a schema, and because of some
   reasons I must use schema version 1.1, so I began my schema header
   like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
```

and I wrote a compleType like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="test-type">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="test"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="test1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4"></xs:element>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

It's valid in version1.1, but invalid in version1.0. When I used my program to parse this schema:

```
xmlSchemaParseCtxtPtr ctxt;
xmlLineNumberDefault(1);
ctxt=xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt("schema.xsd");
_xmlSchema* _schema = xmlSchemaParse(ctxt);
```

I got a null-pointer in _schema.
But if i removed that upper complexType, everything was OK. So I thought may be the root cause was libxml2 only supported schema version1.0 "in my code". So is there any solution to make libxml2 work with schema version1.1? I must use some of its new features.
Any suggestion will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

libxml2 has not been updated to support XSD 1.1. As far as I am aware there is no active development on the product so this is unlikely to happen. You will need to find a different schema processor.

Comment: Hmmm can you give some link ? because I was able to validate the xml with complex types in libxml2. I got stuck at asserts because it is throwing an  error while validating it.

Comment: Complex types are an XSD 1.0 feature and should work fine. Asserts are an XSD 1.1 feature and are not supported in libxml2.

Comment: In 2024 (February 7), with current libxml2 from their master (13962b0), still no support for 1.1: "parser warning : Unsupported version '1.1'".

Comment: While there is a fair bit of "tinkering" activity attempting to improve libxml2, there is no sign of any serious attempt to implement modern W3C standards such as XPath 3.1 or XSD 1.1. Which is not surprising, these are major projects that cannot be done in someone's spare time.