# Does libxml2 supports XSD 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd, libxml2, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

Does libxml2 latest release supports **XSD 1.1** for XML validation?

I am using libxml2 v2.6.30 for XML validation with XSD (schema) 1.0. But, I it does not support XSD v1.1. I am not sure if the latest version of libxml2 supports XSD 1.1 or not. Any idea?

Comment: Not likely.  It's a lot of work, and I've not heard about any such effort even beginning.   See also [Is it possible to validate an XML file against XSD 1.1 in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19809141/290085) and [How to use libxml2 validate a xml with a schema in version 1.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26668140/290085).

Comment: Thank you. It seems a lot of work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

libxml2 does not support XSD 1.1. I found it ultimately after working extensively with libxml2.

Comment: There's an open bug on libxml to support: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765936

Comment: As of 2022, XSD 1.1 is only supported in SaxonEE(commercial) and XercesJ, which are solutions for Java. There are also a few pure Python libraries such as xsd-validator. There are no publicly available  XSD 1.1 validator libraries for C or C++. 
This is quite disappointing.

Comment: @CemPolat Also [xmlschema](https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema) library for Python has full XSD 1.1 support.